# A differentiation/derivative/calculus problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is as follows:

$$y=x^2/(x+1)$$

The normal to this curve at $x=1$ meets the $x$-axis at point $M$.

The tangent to the curve at $x=-2$ meets the $y$-axis at point $N$.

Find the area of triangle $MNO$, where $O$ is the origin.

PS- this is not a school h.w  so don't worry. And I  did try....for  a good 100  min...not even joking

**EDIT** - The drawing is NOT EXACT, it is just to give an idea.
[image]

Comment: Hint: draw a picture... and show us what you tried.

Comment: I found it hard to parse the original problem definitions of $M,N$.  Please check my edit to make sure I did not unintentionally change your meaning.

Comment: @hardmath the edit's good,thanks :)

Comment: @SeanRoberson okayy...I  actually didn't "draw",so that's a good  suggestion

Comment: If you find the coordinates of $M,N$, you should easily compute the are of the triangle.

Comment: I have added an (approximate) image, it may be incorrect, in such a case, remove it.

Comment: @hardmath That's what Im confused about...i did find the coordinates but I'm sure they aren't correct..

Comment: @NoChance the line 1 matches with mine,but the line two...idk, I'm not remnoving  it  because I think  my one's definitely wrong, so ur  one could be right

Comment: @ To find the line equations, we have to find the gradient right? And to find the gradient we have to differentiate y=x2/(x+1), right? But like, what do  we put in the value of x after differentiating?

Comment: tangent for line 2 is **flat**

Comment: Yes, you have to get the derivative to get tangent.

Comment: Can u plz explain how u did the line equation for tangent?

Comment: @NoChance I get it know though, thank you soo  much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{x + 1} = (x + 1)^{-1}x^2; \tag 1$

$y'(x) = -(x + 1)^{-2}x^2 + 2x(x + 1)^{-1} = -(x + 1)^{-2}x^2 + 2x(x + 1)(x + 1)^{-2}$
$= -(x + 1)^{-2}x^2 + (2x^2 + 2x)(x + 1)^{-2} = (x^2 + 2x)(x + 1)^{-2} = \dfrac{x^2 + 2x}{(x + 1)^2}; \tag 2$

$y(1) = \dfrac{1}{2}; \; y'(1) = \dfrac{3}{4}; \tag 3$

$y(-2) = -4; \; y'(-2) = 0; \tag 4$

the slope of the normal line through $(1, y(1)) = (1, 1/2)$ is then

$m = -\dfrac{1}{y'(1)} = -\dfrac{4}{3}; \tag 5$

the equation of the normal line through $(1, 1/2)$ is thus

$y - \dfrac{1}{2} = -\dfrac{4}{3}(x - 1), \tag 6$

which meets the $x$-axis where $y = 0$:

$-\dfrac{1}{2} = -\dfrac{4}{3}(x - 1) \Longrightarrow x = \dfrac{3}{8} + 1 = \dfrac{11}{8}; \tag 7$

thus,

$M = \left (\dfrac{11}{8}, 0 \right); \tag 8$

likewise, the tangent line through  $(-2, y(-2)) = (-2, -4)$ is

$y + 4 = 0(x + 2) = 0, \tag 9$

which intersects the $y$-axis where $x = 0$, with $y$-coordinate given by

$y + 4 = 0 \Longrightarrow y = -4, \tag{10}$

and so

$N = \left (0,  -4 \right ); \tag{11}$

the area $A$ of $\triangle MNO$ is thus

$A = \dfrac{1}{2}ON \cdot OM = \dfrac{1}{2} 4 \cdot  \dfrac{11}{8} = \dfrac{11}{4}. \tag{12}$

Answer (score 2):

Given $y=x^2/(x+1)$, and $f'(\frac{u}v) = (u'v-v'u)/v^2 $
$$y' = \frac{2x(x+1)-(x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2} = \frac{x^2+2x}{(x+1)^2}$$

The normal line's slope is $-\frac1{y'}=-\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+2x}$. For the function, $y(1) = \frac12$ and $y(-2)=-4$

The slope of the normal through $(1,\frac12)$ is $-\frac43$, so the line is $y_1=-\frac43(x-1)+\frac12$. This has an x-intercept of $x-1=\frac34 \cdot \frac12 \to x=\frac{11}8$.

The slope of the tangent through $(-2,-4)$ is $0$, so the y-intercept will be $-4$.

The triangle now has a base $|M-0|$ of $\frac{11}8$ and a height $|N-0|$ of $4$.

Area = $$\frac12 bh=\frac{1*11*4}{2*8*1}=\frac{11}4$$

Comment: how did u know the slope of the tangent through (−2,−4) is 0?

Comment: The tangement does not have to be horizontal - See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent

Comment: @Nabiha21, because when you put $x = -2$ in the $y'$ equation, you get $0$

Comment: @Ohhh, I get it all now, I  had incorrectly used 3/4 as the  tangent's gradient xD Ithanksss everybody<3

Comment: @NoChance The tangent, by definition, must touch the curve at one and only one point. Had the line not been flat, the tangent would have intersected the function twice. Because the tangent to a function at a point has the same slope as the derivative of the function at that point, and because the derivative at that point is zero, the tangent line will have a slope of zero, i.e., it will be flat. True the tangent doesn't **have to be** horizontal, but in this case, it is.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley thanks for the explanation.